# How to switch on Android TV Box without IR Remote Control?

Tags: android-tv

I have recently bought CS928 having RK3288 chipset Android TV Box , which came with IR Remote Control.

IR Remote control can be used to **Start** android tv box and do some other things, but eveytime i have to start the ANDROID TV BOX using IR Remote control , is there any other way to make it Start / Boot as soon as power is connected ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is POWER BUTTON on the TV BOX, its not just to release the camera , its the power button too.,

After Powering On the device , you need to click it once to boot the Android TV Box.

[image: image showing cs9288 power button]

hope this helps.